# Custom metrics in Datadog using PrometheusMeterRegistry

Tags: kotlin, metrics, interceptor, datadog

I am using PrometheusMeterRegistry in my Interceptor code to publish some custom metrics on datadog. I have made the following change in code, however it is not working for me. Can anyone please help me understand why it might be so?

```
@GRpcGlobalInterceptor
class PayloadInterceptor(private val meterRegistry: PrometheusMeterRegistry = PrometheusMeterRegistry(PrometheusConfig.DEFAULT)) : ServerInterceptor {
    override fun <ReqT : Any?, RespT : Any?> interceptCall(
        call: ServerCall<ReqT, RespT>,
        metadata: Metadata,
        next: ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT>,
    ): ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> {
        val headers: Map<String, String> = metadata.keys()
            .associateBy({ it }, { metadata[buildKey(it)] as String })
        val contentType = headers["content-type"]
        contentType?.let { meterRegistry.counter("traveller.api.content.type", "content-type", it).increment() }

        return PayloadServerListener(...)
    }
}
```